# Split string by '|'

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like that A|B|C

How can I split into these strings
s1 = A, s2 = B, s3 = C

I try

```
string str = "A|B|C";
string s3 = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("|") + 1); //get the s3
```

But how can I get the s1 and s2? I forgot I use C#

Comment: What is the language you code in? You should tag your question more precisely.

Comment: What language are you using?  Add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Is this C#? Seems so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all languages have the split functionality with this signature:

```
string.split(delimeter, optional_number_of_splits)
```

returns an array

For example in C#:

```
string myStr = "A|B|C";
string[] parts = myStr.Split('|');
```

Answer (score 0):

The splitting can be done as follows.

```
string[] Parts
    = str.Split(new string[]{"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
```